# How to get the best visual output for my java program

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making a java software. It's a sort of reminder with enhanced functionnalities. You create a sticker in a window, and you write whatever you want. You can link stickers within a window or/and link window between them.

For that I need to implement graphical interface that permits me to give a sense of perspective, depth (for example I can link a windows located on a z-index of 10 with a windows located on a z-index of 2)

What kind of stuff can I use?
I put my hands in swing, and it seems to be pretty static, i was thinking maybe about opengl. Are there lighter perspectives for me?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422956/java-swing-or-java-qt

Comment: You might want to take a look at "Killer Games Programming in Java" which gives a good breakdown of using Swing, Java3D and JOGL (in 2nd Ed.) for creating animation frameworks in Java -  http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/

Comment: thank you trevor, i will check at this book.

Answer (score 1):

[Javafx](http://javafx.com/) is easier than swing. The [sdk](http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp) comes with lots of examples. After extracting the sdk go to the apps folder and there you will find an Example called Ensemble.jar.

You need to download and install the runtime before trying the examples.

You can use the toFront() toBack() methods to bring nodes to front and back respectively.
Javafx 1.3 supports 3D drawings, im not sure if version 2.0 supports it.

Note: Javafx 2.0 is still in beta.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about Qt Jambi? It is a Qt interface implemented in Java.

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell if it's genious or ridiculous idea;)
I am gonna check the informations, thank you androslav.